# Extracting audio features from real-time input, using OpenSMILE

Tags: audio, feature-extraction

I can extract features from audio files stored in system, using OpenSMILE. But I need to extract features in real-time, using the same OpenSMILE. Is it possible, without saving the recorded audio file?

Answer (score 2):

It seems it may support it. From the [manual](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensmile/files/openSMILE_book_1.0.0.pdf)

> To check if your SMILExtract binary supports live audio recording and
>   playback, type:
>   `SMILExtract -H cPortaudio`

and

> The components cPortaudioSource and cPortaudioSink can be used as
>   replacements for cWaveSource and cWaveSink. They produce/expect data
>   in the same format as the wave components.

Hooray for internet searching...

Answer (score 1):

You might also need a cTurnDetector component (see the SIG'MM tutorial referenced at http://opensmile.audeering.com/) and a VAD to enable segmentation of your live input for some features (functionals).

Also check out: [How to create custom config files in OpenSMILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555779/how-to-create-custom-config-files-in-opensmile) to see how you can customize configuration files and set the buffer sizes correctly (in live mode it is important to use ring buffers to avoid growing memory consumption).

Answer (score 0):

It works properly if you build the openSMILE with portAudio :)

According to manual:

... A live feature extraction example is provided, which
**captures live audio and extracts prosodic features** (pitch and loudness contours) from the input.
The features are saved to a CSV le. To use this conguration, type:

*SMILExtract -C config/liveProsodyAcf.conf*